# Is the input event reliable?

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

I'm looking for a input change event, that fires when:

- a option is selected inside a select box
- a checkbox is checked
- value of text field was changed, or the value is being changed (typing or pasted something / deleted part of text etc)

I found "input" but will this work in all browsers? because I don't see it listed in the jQuery doc?

Comment: Have you tried `change`?

Comment: yes, and it doesn't fire if I'm typing something

Comment: Does the one event have to catch them all? as @Juhana said change is good for 1 and 2, but keyup is needed for the third.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're asking for different things.

In 1 & 2, the change event would suit your needs. However while the change event would also work for 3, it is only fired once the field loses focus. In case 3 you'd want to use one of the keyboard events (keydown, keyup, keypress).